# How to check if a requested file exists in WEB-INF from a Java Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm writing a filter which redirects a `.js` file to its corresponding `.js.gz` file, if it exists. So foo.js would go to foo.js.gz. The problem is, how do I check if the corresponding .js.gz file exists in the WEB-INF directory from the servlet?

Currently, if I do

```
System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
File f = new File( httpServletRequest.getRequestURI() ); 
System.out.println( f.exists);
```

I get:

```
/test.js
false
```

Even when the file exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I check if the corresponding .js.gz file exists in the WEB-INF directory from the servlet?

Use [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/foo.js.gz"));
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
if(file.exists()){
    System.out.println("file exists");
}
```

For more info read comments below.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I have to specify /WEB-INF, simply doing `String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath( request.getRequestURI() ); File f = new File(path);` seems to give the correct results.

Comment: and `request.getRequestURI()` gives something like `/foo.js`

Comment: Test it at your end and add `.gz` in the end of the file name.